# AEM 6: Not able to change the dimension of xtype tabpanel

Tags: extjs, aem

I am trying to load the tabs as per the change of value in dropdown. I am getting the error box.findParentByType(...).manageTabs is not a function. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    height="{Long}600"
    manageTabs="function(tab,noSwitch){var tabs=['tab1','tab2','tab3'];var index=tabs.indexOf(tab);if(index==-1) return;for(var i=5;i&amp;lt;tabs.length;i++){if(index==i){this.unhideTabStripItem(i);}else{this.hideTabStripItem(i);}}this.doLayout();if(!noSwitch)this.activate(index);}"
    title="Campaign Tiles Configurations"
    width="{Long}1000"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Campaign Tiles">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <campaigns
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldDescription="Press + to add more"
                        fieldLabel="Configure Tiles"
                        name="./campaigns"
                        width="1000"
                        xtype="multifield">
                        <fieldConfig
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            name="./fieldConfig"
                            xtype="multifieldpanel">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <headline
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="Provide headline for the individual tile"
                                    fieldLabel="Headline"
                                    key="headline"
                                    width="{Long}560"
                                    xtype="textfield"/>
                                <iconImage
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="Drag and drop or select the image in this field"
                                    fieldLabel="Icon Image"
                                    key="iconImage"
                                    rootPath="/content/dam"
                                    width="{Long}560"
                                    xtype="ddpathfield"/>
                                <description
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="Provide description for the individual tile"
                                    fieldLabel="Description"
                                    key="description"
                                    width="{Long}560"
                                    xtype="textfield"/>
                                <subdescription
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="Provide sub-description for the individual tile. Use the mapping {{name}} above."
                                    fieldLabel="Sub-description"
                                    key="subdescription"
                                    width="{Long}560"
                                    xtype="textfield"/>
                                <buttonText
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="Text to be applied on the button"
                                    fieldLabel="Button Text"
                                    key="buttonText"
                                    width="{Long}560"
                                    xtype="textfield"/>
                                <url
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="URL on which the page navigates after the button is clicked"
                                    fieldLabel="URL"
                                    key="url"
                                    rootPath="/content/XXXXX"
                                    width="{Long}560"
                                    xtype="pathfield"/>
                                <external
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldLabel="Open in a separate tab ?"
                                    key="external"
                                    labelStyle="width:155px"
                                    xtype="checkbox"/>
                                <visible
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldLabel="Make VISIBLE?"
                                    key="visible"
                                    labelStyle="width:155px"
                                    xtype="checkbox"/>
                                <selectList
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
                                    fieldDescription="These are the items on which the rules selected above will be applied"
                                    fieldLabel="Provide Options"
                                    key="selectList"
                                    type="select"
                                    xtype="selection">
                                    <listeners
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        loadcontent="function(){this.findParentByType('tabpanel').manageTabs(this.getValue(),true);}"
                                        selectionchanged="function(box,value){box.findParentByType('tabpanel').manageTabs(value);}"/>
                                    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                        <claims
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            key="claims"
                                            text="Claims"
                                            value="claims"/>
                                        <plansandbenefits
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            key="plansandbenefits"
                                            text="Plans &amp; Benefits"
                                            value="plansandbenefits"/>
                                    </options>
                                </selectList>
                            </items>
                        </fieldConfig>
                    </campaigns>
                </items>
            </tab1>
            <tab2
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                anchor="100%"
                title="Campaign Placeholders"
                xtype="panel">
                <listeners
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    render="function() { this.findParentByType('tabpanel').hideTabStripItem(1); }"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <campaign_placeholders
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        defaultValue="[{name},{DoB}]"
                        disabled="{Boolean}true"
                        emptyText="[{name},{DoB}]"
                        fieldDescription="These placeholders should be used while creating content. These are responsible for binding data from the back end."
                        fieldLabel="Placeholders"
                        name="/placeholders"
                        xtype="textarea"/>
                </items>
            </tab2>
            <tab3
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                anchor="100%"
                title="Plans &amp; Benefits Placeholders"
                xtype="panel">
                <listeners
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    render="function() { this.findParentByType('tabpanel').hideTabStripItem(2); }"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <plansbenefits_placeholders
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        defaultValue="[{name},{DoB}]"
                        disabled="{Boolean}true"
                        emptyText="[{name},{DoB}]"
                        fieldDescription="These placeholders should be used while creating content. These are responsible for binding data from the back end."
                        fieldLabel="Placeholders"
                        name="/placeholders"
                        xtype="textarea"/>
                </items>
            </tab3>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

The difference here is that the options dropdown lives in a multifield.

Thanks in advance

===============================

Here is an update. I have been able to resolve the issue by doing some changes in the structure. But now the issue is I am not able to change the height and width of the dialog. Here is the updated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    boxMinHeight="{Long}600"
    boxMinWidth="{Long}1000"
    height="{Long}600"
    manageTabs="function(tab,noSwitch){var tabs=['campaign','claims','benefits'];var index=tabs.indexOf(tab);if(index==-1) return;for(var i=1;i&lt;tabs.length;i++){if(index==i){this.unhideTabStripItem(i);}else{this.hideTabStripItem(i);}}this.doLayout();if(!noSwitch)this.activate(index);}"
    title="Campaigns"
    width="{Long}1000"
    xtype="tabpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <campaign
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            height="{Long}600"
            title="Campaigns"
            width="{Long}1000"
            xtype="panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <campaigns
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldDescription="Press + to add more"
                    fieldLabel="Configure Tiles"
                    name="./campaigns"
                    width="1000"
                    xtype="multifield">
                    <fieldConfig
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        name="./fieldConfig"
                        xtype="multifieldpanel">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <headline
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldDescription="Provide headline for the individual tile"
                                fieldLabel="Headline"
                                key="headline"
                                width="{Long}560"
                                xtype="textfield"/>
                            <iconImage
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldDescription="Drag and drop or select the image in this field"
                                fieldLabel="Icon Image"
                                key="iconImage"
                                rootPath="/content/dam"
                                width="{Long}560"
                                xtype="ddpathfield"/>
                            <description
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldDescription="Provide description for the individual tile"
                                fieldLabel="Description"
                                key="description"
                                width="{Long}560"
                                xtype="textfield"/>
                            <subdescription
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldDescription="Provide sub-description for the individual tile. Use the mapping {{name}} above."
                                fieldLabel="Sub-description"
                                key="subdescription"
                                width="{Long}560"
                                xtype="textfield"/>
                            <buttonText
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldDescription="Text to be applied on the button"
                                fieldLabel="Button Text"
                                key="buttonText"
                                width="{Long}560"
                                xtype="textfield"/>
                            <url
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldDescription="URL on which the page navigates after the button is clicked"
                                fieldLabel="URL"
                                key="url"
                                rootPath="/content/XXXXX"
                                width="{Long}560"
                                xtype="pathfield"/>
                            <external
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldLabel="Open in a separate tab ?"
                                key="external"
                                labelStyle="width:155px"
                                xtype="checkbox"/>
                            <visible
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldLabel="Make VISIBLE?"
                                key="visible"
                                labelStyle="width:155px"
                                xtype="checkbox"/>
                            <selectList
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
                                fieldDescription="These are the items on which the rules selected above will be applied"
                                fieldLabel="Provide Options"
                                key="selectList"
                                type="select"
                                xtype="selection">
                                <listeners
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    loadcontent="function(){this.findParentByType('tabpanel').manageTabs(this.getValue(),true);}"
                                    selectionchanged="function(box,value){box.findParentByType('tabpanel').manageTabs(value);}"/>
                                <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <claims
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="Claims"
                                        value="claims"/>
                                    <benefits
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="Benefits"
                                        value="benefits"/>
                                </options>
                            </selectList>
                        </items>
                    </fieldConfig>
                </campaigns>
            </items>
        </campaign>
        <claims
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            height="{Long}600"
            title="Claims"
            width="{Long}1000"
            xtype="panel">
            <listeners
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                render="function() { this.findParentByType('tabpanel').hideTabStripItem(1); }"/>
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <parentPage
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldDescription="Leave empty to use current page"
                    fieldLabel="Parent page"
                    name="./parentPage"
                    xtype="pathfield"/>
            </items>
        </claims>
        <benefits
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            height="{Long}600"
            title="Benefits"
            width="{Long}1000"
            xtype="panel">
            <listeners
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                render="function() { this.findParentByType('tabpanel').hideTabStripItem(2); }"/>
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <ancestorPage
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldDescription="Leave empty to use current page"
                    fieldLabel="Parent page"
                    name="./ancestorPage"
                    xtype="pathfield"/>
            </items>
        </benefits>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change `xtype="tabpanel"` to `xtype="dialog"`